# Netsuite Webservice SOAP request in .net core for Vendor Searches

Tags: c#, .net-core, netsuite

I'm starting to test connecting to our sandbox in netsuite and would like to request a vendor record. We're using version 2022.1 wsdl within the project and .net core 3.1. Here is the code i'm using which return invalid internalid reference. here is my code below..

```
NetSuitePortTypeClient service = new NetSuitePortTypeClient(NetSuitePortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.NetSuitePort, "https://[Account-ID].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2022_1");

        VendorSearchBasic vendorSearch = new VendorSearchBasic();
        vendorSearch.internalId = new SearchMultiSelectField();
        vendorSearch.internalId.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        vendorSearch.internalId.operatorSpecified = true;
        vendorSearch.internalId.searchValue = new RecordRef[1];
        vendorSearch.internalId.searchValue[0] = new RecordRef();
        vendorSearch.internalId.searchValue[0].internalId = "Test API Vendor";

        return await service.searchAsync(Shared.createTokenPassport(), null, null, null, vendorSearch);
```

Comment: I tried using the externalID as well but doesn't work

Comment: I am using 2020.1 and copied your VendorBasic code and it worked for me.  Does the role making the request have access to Vendor records?

Comment: do you have any experience adding custom transactions using soap and c#?  i"ve got another process i'm trying to create a new entry but get 'Invalid custom transaction type identifier'